# Pushing war/war file from jenkins to Tomcat server v 8.x or 9.x

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins for continuous build for java projects and i am using deploy plugin,it takes a war/ear file and deploys that to a running remote application server at the end of a build successful.

Using deploy plugin i am able to take war/ear file from jenkins and deploy that to a running remote application server at the end of a build successful but it is supporting till tomcat7 but latest version of tomcat is 9.

Could you please help me which plugin i have to use so that i can deploy war/ear file to tomcat 8 or tomcat 9?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) would work fine with Tomcat 8 as well, even though it says it supports up to 7.x

I haven't tested with Tomcat9 yet.